# .htaccess for rewrite url affecting web-dev folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, deflate

Okay there is 2 questions,

First, I'm new with htaccess and have a lot of problem figure out how to make good Rewrited URL for google SEO so i've made this :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

### [... other language ...]


### English product URL

# Product page : (url/en/products/items-1.html)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[P-p]roducts/item-([0-9]+)\.html$   produits.php?lang=$1&art=$2 [L,NC]

# List of categories of a division (url/en/products/items-1-1.html)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[P-p]roducts/item-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$   produits.php?lang=$1&idc=$2&catd=$3 [L,NC]

# List of subcategories of a categorie (url/en/products/items-1-1-1.html) 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[P-p]roducts/item-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$   produits.php?lang=$1&idc=$2&catd=$3&catt=$4 [L,NC]

# List of sub-sub-categories of a sub-categorie (url/en/products/items-1-1-1-1.html)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[P-p]roducts/item-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ produits.php?lang=$1&idc=$2&catd=$3&catt=$4&catq=$5 [L,NC]

### Mod Rewrite to make url more friendly EN
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[B-b]ecome-a-[C-c]lient client.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[C-c]ontact-[U-u]s contact.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[O-o]ops erreur.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[I-i]ndustrial-[D-d]ivision industriel.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[C-c]art panier.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[S-s]earch recherche.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[H-h]ealt-[D-d]ivision sanitaire.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/[H-h]ome index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC]

### Compression Mod
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

## [... errors page ...]
```

The problem now is that if I would reach something for developpement purpose I can't do it

Exemple : I copy the whole website into a folder named work a the root of the domain so the url would be

www.website-url.com/work

at this point everything is fine I can access this part, but if I would access products.php I just can do it... I know that I can't reach it with the rewrite like www.website-url.com/work/products/items-1.html but I should be able to access it directly no ?

My second questions is that I would use compression for my server to make the website load more faster for client because I have a lot of javascipt working with jQuery a lot. But I can't make it work, I've checked with online tools and never pass compression test.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are the name changes "products" -> "produits" and "industrial" -> "industriel" intentional?

Comment: Are you aware that `[P-p]` is the `PQRST...XYZabcd...mnop` range?

Comment: MattJ yeah that intentional because of multilanguage i'm french so all my php files name is in french and I rename it using mod rewrite, 


Alvaro, no I was thinking that [P-p] is for UPPERCASE-lowercase of P !

Comment: Thats [Pp]. You should be able to access it directly as long as none of your quite liberal rewriting rules apply. That work/... solution though seems to be very hard to implement since all the links would go haywire.

Comment: Its been a while but second question should be a separate question if it isn't already